# MYSQL Error: ip cannot be null

Tags: mysql, null

I am having an insert command as below

```
   Insert into table1 (host, ip, domain ) 
    select hostname, (case when t1.ip is null then 'Not Defined' end) , domain from table1 t1, table2 t2 
    where t1.status = "Done"
    and t2.statusnew not regexp "True"
    limit 10 ;
```

Getting Error: `ip cannot be null`

Comment: What's the data type of ip in table1? Btw the 2 source tables are not joined.

Comment: the data type is `varchar(45)`

Comment: Just try `case when t1.ip is null then 'Not Defined' else t1.ip end`

Comment: thanks it is working!